# How to show emoji on button click that animates then disappears in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, 2d-games, flutter-animation

So I'm developing this game called Tap Tap, and what is required is that when I click a button a like emoji should appear, animate to top then disappear, kinda like when like button is clicked in instagram, a heart appears.

How can I achieve something like this in flutter, I don't want anything fancy, just the emoji to show for like a second, animate then disappear.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to animate the opacity and offset.

Wrap the emoji with an AnimatedOpacity widget and wrap that with a TransformWidget.